# Как узнать для даты количество секунд, прошедших с 1970 года?

Tags: unixtimestamp, java

Подскажите, как можно узнать количество секунд, прошедших с 1970 для любой даты.
У меня есть `String data="2013-07-07"`. Как мне узнать количество сек?

Answer (score 3):

Распарси строку, чтобы получить год, месяц, день.

Затем используй GregorianCalendar:

```
    GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(2013, 7, 7);
    Long secs = date.getTimeInMillis()/1000;
```

Вместо 2013, 7 и 7 передавай переменные, которые получил в результате парсинга.

Comment: а еще можно поизвращатся так :

        Date dNow = new Date( );
        SimpleDateFormat fdd = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd");
        SimpleDateFormat fMM = new SimpleDateFormat ("MM");
        SimpleDateFormat fyyyy = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy");
        int dd = Integer.parseInt(fdd.format(dNow)),
         MM = Integer.parseInt(fMM.format(dNow)),
         yyyy = Integer.parseInt(fyyyy.format(dNow));
        
  
  GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar(yyyy, MM, dd);
     Long secs = date.getTimeInMillis()/1000;